# Installing Yii2 via composer failed

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-basic-app

I want to install yii2 via composer and it's give me a error

here is error:

```
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.5 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

also i installed latest version of composer-asset-plugin.
i cleared composer cache and update it.
but i can't install yii2-basic anyway

it's my composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "*",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "^1.1",
        "phpunit/dbunit" : "^2.0",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.2.0"
    },
    "minimum-stablility‬‬": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/Codeception/YiiBridge",
            "reference": "origin/master"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "2.2.2",
        "codeception/YiiBridge": "dev-master",
        "flow/jsonpath": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: restart your system!

Comment: try run composer self update

Comment: Change `"minimum-stablility‬‬": "dev"` to `"minimum-stablility‬‬": "stable"`

Answer (score 16):

As Yii 2 is bound to the [fxp/composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin) you have to install the fxp plugin to your composer *environment*. The fxp plugin must be installed **globally**. You can achieve this with the following command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4"
```

After sucessfull installation of the fxp plugin remove the requirement from your *require* section in the composer.json and run `composer update` again.

[How to install FXP composer plugin Docs](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Comment: Yii2 will hopefully drop the fxp plugin requirement with version 2.1 as i could read from the [next major version plans](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/wiki/Plan-for-next-major-versions#client-side) in the wiki.

Comment: we can also install it locally `php composer.phar require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.2"` . BTW thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when I run `composer update`

I solved it by install command instead of update

```
composer install
```

Also you can try to update composer at first

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [yii2-bower-asset](https://github.com/yidas/yii2-bower-asset) without using `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` to install Bower for Yii2.

This package has fixed Bower for Yii2, which separates Bower and Composer.

> https://github.com/yidas/yii2-bower-asset

---

By the way, Yii 2.1 is going to use Asset Packagist solution instead of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by following steps.

Step 1: Delete th file `composer.lock` from project folder

Step 2: Delete the `vendor` folder

Step 3: Run the command `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4"`

Step 4: Run `composer update`